# Como pegar o value e label de um datalist usando jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Tenho um `datalist`, que uso assim:

```
<input id="estabelecimento" list="listaEstabelecimento"/>
<datalist id="listaEstabelecimento">
  <option value="valor1" label="label1"></option>
</datalist>
```

Uso esse componente para fazer o efeito `autocomplete`. No código, eu uso `$("#estabelecimento").val()` para filtrar os dados. Usando `$("#estabelecimento").val()` ele me retorna o `label1`. Como faço pra pegar o `valor1`? Pois preciso dele também.

Comment: Esse `datalist` está associado a um `input`, certo? Então por quê está pegando o valor do `datalist` e não do `input`?

Comment: Escrevi errado, uso assim igual alterei agora

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o comando `$("#estabelecimento").val()` retorna o que está dentro de `value`. Ao que parece você quer retornar o que está dentro do `label` do objeto option da datalist. Você pode percorrer os options dentro do objeto datalist usando um `for` e comparando os valores, como abaixo:

```js
$("#estabelecimento").change(function(){

  var valor = $("#estabelecimento").val();
  var label;
  
  var options = document.getElementById("listaEstabelecimento").options;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    
    if(options[i].value == valor) {
      label = options[i].label;
    }
    
    if(label != null) break;
    
  }
  
  console.log("Valor: " + valor + ", Label: " + label);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="estabelecimento" list="listaEstabelecimento"/>
<datalist id="listaEstabelecimento">
  <option value="valor1" label="label1"></option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Forma bem simples:**

```js
//Listando apenas um valor, clicando sobre o option:
$("#estabelecimento").on('change', function() {

  var _this = $(this);

  $('#listaEstabelecimento').find('option').each((index, el) => {

      if (_this.val() === el.value) {

          prompt('', el.value + ' ' + el.label);

      }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="estabelecimento" list="listaEstabelecimento" />
<datalist id="listaEstabelecimento">
  <option value="valor1" label="label1"></option>
  <option value="valor2" label="label2"></option>
  <option value="valor3" label="label3"></option>
</datalist>
```